# ASP.NET - Validate a user without logging them in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to validate a user's Username + Password *without* logging them in? I understand a usual login block will look like this:

```
if (!Page.IsValid)
 return;

if (Membership.ValidateUser(UsernameInput.Text, PasswordInput.Text))
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameInput.Text, false);
}
else { [...] }
```

With the **Membership.ValidateUser()** call setting the cookie for the response.

However, there are some additional checks I'd like to perform after the password is confirmed. (Pulling out an expiry date for that user, for example).

Is there a way to do it without just calling **FormsAuthentication.SignOut();** after invalidating the page?

Comment: Do you neeed to validation like that if the username/password exsits in the database?

Comment: @Overflow; how about just calling `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()`?

Comment: @BeemerGuy: Won't work: "The Authenticate method verifies user credentials that are stored in the credentials section of the application configuration file. Alternatively, you can use ASP.NET membership to store user credentials and call the ValidateUser to verify the credentials."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your assumption that [Membership.ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) is setting the cookie is wrong. I don't believe it sets cookies.

[FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) sets the cookie.

Think about it from a separation of concerns standpoint:

**Membership** is where you store your users and password, but it really doesn't know anything about the web or cookies.

**Forms Authentication** is the technology that keeps a user logged into a website but doesn't care how you determine if that user is valid. All it cares about is having a username and setting/reading cookies, so that the user doesn't have to log in with every 
request.